# Can I use 'genstring' in terminal on mac to only add new Localized Strings to Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, internationalization

When running genstrings, all the added localizations in Localizable.strings are reverted back to base lang. Are genstrings only for when the app is finished and you want to translate it? Isn't there a way to only make the untranslated ones be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the tool genstrings will only create new localizable.strings files for all localized strings when ran.